# Oracle Apex - Interactive report download issue

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have Interactive report with 15 columns.
For downloading report i used Download function from Action menu.
When I tried to download  report in csv format with 10 selected coulmn.. Csv does not contain all that selected 10 columns.
Only few columns are shown in csv file

Comment: How do you know that less than the selected 10 columns are being downloaded? Perhaps check the CSV file in notepad. Also, check if there are any Server-Side Conditions on any of the columns which might evaluate to False when the report is being run for the download.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle APEX uses the same query defined for HTML output to generate the csv for download, it applies same rules that is applied on HTML(from apex builder) report.
If you are seeing any gaps, that must be due to settings.
Try to open the report in incognito mode and download it.

Comment: I tried to download report in incognito mode but no luck.

Comment: what is the sql query you are using, share your select clause

Comment: I have used simple select query for Interactive report. And In attribute of IR I used inbuilt download function for csv. But when I applied filter on columns of report then after downloading csv file, only few columns are showned in that file